# python3 start loop based on key pressed

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a loop when I click on the insert key and stop the loop when I enter the end screen, but this isn't happening and I don't know why, another thing I wanted to do was use two keys combined within the loop like:

alt left + 2

can anybody help me?

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

STATUS = True

def on_release(key:Key):
    global STATUS
    if key == Key.insert :
        STATUS = False
    if key == Key.end:
        print(3)
        STATUS = True

def main():
    global STATUS

    with Listener(
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
    while STATUS:
        print('on loop')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

STATUS = False

def on_press(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.insert:
        
        STATUS = True

def on_release(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.end:
        
        STATUS = False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    
    while STATUS:
        
        print('on loop')
        
        pass

    listener.join()
```

**for two keys combined within the loop use Keycode from pynput.keyboard**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, KeyCode

def on_press(key):
    
    if key == KeyCode(char='2') and Key.alt_l.value:
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup for hotkeys like CTRL+C, and so you can use multiple of combinations of Hotkeys to do different things.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, KeyCode

STATUS = True
PROCESSING = True
PressedKeys = set()
AnyKey = TypeVar('AnyKey', int, Key, KeyCode)
HotkeyCombos = [
    {Key.ctrl_l, Key.alt_l, 67},  # CTRL+ALT+C for breaking the main loop
    {Key.insert},
    {Key.end}
]


def on_press(pressed: AnyKey):
    if isinstance(pressed, KeyCode):
        pressed = pressed.vk

    if pressed not in PressedKeys:
        PressedKeys.add(pressed)

        for hotkeys in HotkeyCombos:
            if all(key in PressedKeys for key in hotkeys):
                for key in hotkeys:
                    if key == pressed:
                        if hotkeys == HotkeyCombos[0]:
                            PROCESSING = False
                        if hotkeys == HotkeyCombos[1]:
                            STATUS = False
                        if hotkeys == HotkeyCombos[2]:
                            print(3)
                            STATUS = True


def on_release(key: AnyKey):
    if isinstance(key, KeyCode):
        key = key.vk

    if key in PressedKeys:
        PressedKeys.remove(key)


with Listener(on_press = on_press, on_release = on_release) as keyboard:
    while PROCESSING:
        while STATUS:
            print('on loop')

    keyboard.join()
```